# Is it possible to see the values returned by Hyperledger Composer transaction Processor in Browser

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is there any way to see values returned by Hyperledger composer transaction processor from Hyperledger composer playground in browser.

I tried enabling logs in chrome browser but unable to see values returned from transaction processor.

I am debugging composer business network in online playground , so looking to understand if i could see values returned from transaction processor function. I am able to see statements printed via console.log() in browser but unable to catch hold of values returned by processor.

```
 * Transaction Created to add the new property in the system
 * @param {org.example.property.example} tx
 * @returns {string}
 * @transaction
 */
async function example(tx) {
    return 'hello world!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Runtime(Local) Log :**

If you run `docker ps -a` you should see basic running **docker containers**. One of the docker containers will be a **chaincode container** (your running business network). You will see particular **container id** of container.

Then look forward using `docker logs <container id>` you will see your **console.log()** information and **transaction return** information in your **terminal**.

**Developer log :**

you can see the output in the Developer console. In Firefox and Chrome browsers for example - hit CTRL-SHIFT-I and it pops up - then go to Console.and you can see what your console log information.

Comment: I did ask for web browser if i could see returned value in composer playground. So far i have not installed business network locally. Let me see if above steps works.

Comment: @RAJSINGH I edited answer. review it. I hope it will help you :)